# How to render Image on the web page using path from DB in Django?

Tags: python, django

[image]
So I am trying to display an image on the web page, i save the image path in the database as media/imagename and in my html page i am doing this :

```
{% for stuff in profile %}
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> {{ stuff.text }} </div>

    <img scr='/Users/Username/PycharmProjects/social-django-1.9/mysite/media/media/{{ stuff.thumbnail }}' width="200">

{% endfor %}
```

And in my settings.py i do this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '/Users/Username/PycharmProjects/social-django-1.9/mysite/media/media')
```

But the image doesn't display. What am i doing wrong here? Thanks!

Edit:

```
#urls.py
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
 from django.conf import settings

 from social import views


 urlpatterns = [


# main page
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
# signup page
url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
# register new user
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
# login page
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
# user doesnt exist webpage
url(r'^user-doesnt-exist/$', views.login, name='user-doesnt-exist'),
#page to show that the password is incorrect
url(r'^wrongpass/$', views.login, name='wrongpass'),
#webpage to show an error when a user tries to input nothing in the fields when signing up
url(r'^novalues/$', views.register, name='novalues'),
# logout page
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
# members page
url(r'^members/$', views.members, name='members'),
#invites page
url(r'^invites/$', views.invites, name='invites'),
# friends page
url(r'^friends/$', views.friends, name='friends'),
# user profile edit page
url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
# messages page
url(r'^messages/$', views.messages, name='messages'),
# Ajax: check if user exists
url(r'^checkuser/$', views.checkuser, name='checkuser'),
#commiting again


]


if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns(''(r'^media/(P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve',
                         {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT,'show_indexes':True})),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your `MEDIA_ROOT` to:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'social/static/social/media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And in your project `urls.py` file add:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}))
```

Then, in your template call the image like:

```
{% if stuff.thumbnail %}
    <img src="{{ object.thumbnail.url  }}">
{% endif %}
```

And in `models.py`:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)'s some great documentation on serving media files, including how to serve them during development.

Comment: I am sorry i must be doing something wrong, but i think i should be putting the `if settings.DEBUG` bit at the end of my `url patterns =[ ]` but i am getting this error `'list' object has no attribute 'regex'` ... Where am i supposed to be putting that bit of code in the settings?

Comment: You're correct, it should go after your urls. Make sure it's outside the `urlpatterns` list. To be safe, add a few blank lines after the closing bracket for the list and then add the `if settings.DEBUG` statement. Also make sure you've imported `settings` in your urls file with `from django.conf import settings`. If this doesn't fix it, perhaps you could add your urls to your question with a quick edit.

Comment: Sorry didnt see to make it work here, updated my question, thanks for your help

Comment: Directly after the `if settings.DEBUG`, is `urlpatterns += patterns...` indented? It should be indented - not sure if the edit you posted has a typo or not but your edit doesn't show it indented, so Python wouldn't interpret that as an action to follow based on the condition

Comment: Thank you i guess that was the problem. So i did that and unfortunately it gave me an error `The 'thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it.`

Comment: I updated the template code in my answer with a condition around the thumbnail - so add that condition. Also make sure your image field's `upload_to` argument is set, so for instance if you want your media to be in `/project_path/media/photos` you'd set `upload_to='photos/'`. It might also be worth re-uploading the photo/thumbnail to make sure it's uploaded to the correct location now that your media_root is changed

Comment: Okay so now instead of displaying nothing it displays a little box with a question mark (i assume it suggests that the link in broken) and i get this error in the webpage : `404 (not found)`  at http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/media/10.jpg  and i assume it just is confused with the path.. what would you suggest doing in this case?

Comment: I would check to make sure you have a `MEDIA_URL` set in your project settings. For instance: `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Yeah i had set it before and it still can't find the image.. just so confused with these paths atm

Comment: Also you mentioned to set upload_to='photos/' where would i do that? in my models?

Comment: You got it - in your models. An example would be `image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')`. This, paired with the other examples I've given in my answer would make your path to the image `/<your_project_path>/media/images/someimage.jpg`

Comment: So i have tried that but it just displays the `media/filename.jpg` path on the page but it doesn't display the actual image..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104654/discussion-between-curtis-olson-and-user3395936).